# Where to put response messages in laravel api?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In my laravel 5.5 api I have a lot of response message like 
"You successfully completed some action..".

At the moment I have stored them as constants in the controller they
are used. I want to move all of them to a single location, so if I need to change them later I don't have to hunt for them in each controller.

What is the best approach for this usecase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [Laravel localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization)? Then using it as `trans('success-message-key-here')`

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the translations files even if you are just supporting one language.

In your controller you would have something like:

```
$message = \Lang::get('directory/file.str1');
```

And your translation file:

```
return [
   'str1' => 'You successfully completed some action.',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

In your use case, I would make static functions to call the responses the same way.

```
class ResponseMessage
{
    public static function succesfulResponse()
    {
        return response('successfull', 200);
    }

    public static function failedResponse()
    {
        return response('fail', 400);
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
...

return ResponseMessage::succesfulResponse();
```

Another way is to take the parent controller, which is often just named `Controller` in your controller folder, which you extend from.

```
class controller
{
    public function succesfulResponse()
    {
        return response('successfull', 200);
    }
}
```

Now you are not in a static context, but you can use the functions if you extend from it.

```
class yourController extends Controller
{
    public function get($id) {
        ...

        return $this->succesfulResponse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `resource/lang/en` directory (in other words [Localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization) you can put your message like this

**ApiMessage.php**

```
return [

    'success' => 'success message',

];
```

Then in your controller you can call like this

```
public function somefunction(Request $request)
    {
        // your logic 
        return response()->json(__('apiMessages.success'));
    }
```

here `en` folder denotes your local language (default is english symbolized as en)